# Foundation transparent table

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to create a transparent table using the Foundation framework. I achived this without the framework but it seems i just can't using it.Any sugestions would be great.

```
table {
    text-align: center;
}
table thead th{
    text-align: center;
}
tbody tr th{
    font-weight: normal;
}
th{ 
    background-color: rgba(251,169,17,0.5);
}
td{ 
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 10em;
    outline: 3px solid #e3e3e3;
    /*border: 1px solid rgba(251,169,17,.5);*/
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
td:hover{
    background-color: #CEE3F6;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Foundation, the background colour is given to the `thead` and `tbody` elements. To override these, simply use the following:

```css
table thead,
table tbody {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I will look for it. Thank for the answer

Comment: @zaa I've completely changed my answer as what I'd previously put didn't really apply here. Hopefully my update will solve your problem.